# Problema em um simples Update com Inner Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou executando um simples update na minha base, porém o `set` que estou dando, está sendo replicado para todas as linhas da tabela.

Segue o script executado:

```
update reference_vendor set internalid = v.internal_id 
from reference_vendor rv
inner join contract_reference v on v.external_id = rv.externalid
where v.id = '1207847'
and v.record_type = 'vendor'
```

No caso acima eu passo na cláusula where o id que eu quero dar o update, porém ele está replicando para todas as linhas.

Segue o print:

[image: dados]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Segue estrutura da tabela:

reference_vendor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

contract_reference:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não costumo usar from no update, mas se a sintaxe está correta, deveria ser algo assim: `update reference_vendor set reference_vendor.internalid = v.internal_id 
from contract_reference v on v.external_id = reference_vendor.externalid
where v.id = '1207847'
and v.record_type = 'vendor'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque você não tem nenhum critério sobre a tabela que esta sendo atualizada.

Veja, você tem:

```
update reference_vendor set internalid = v.internal_id
```

`reference_vendor`  é a tabela que você quer atualizar.

Depois você tem a fonte de dados para a atualização:

```
from reference_vendor rv
inner join contract_reference v on v.external_id = rv.externalid
```

Por último, o critério para quais linhas você vai atualizar:

```
where v.id = '1207847' and v.record_type = 'vendor'
```

Como você repetiu a tabela `reference_vendor` (uma para o update e outra para o from) e não incluiu nenhum critério que limite as linhas da tabela que está sendo atualizada, o update é aplicado sobre toda a tabela.

A forma correta de fazer essa consulta é:

```
update reference_vendor set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and v.id = '1207847'
and v.record_type = 'vendor'
```

A leitura é a seguinte:

> atualize o campo internalid  da tabela reference_vendor selecionando
>   os registros que correpondem aos registros de contract_reference  id =
>   '1207847' e record_type = 'vendor' usando o campo externalid como
>   junção

Somente como comparação, a query original pode ser lida assim:

> atualize o campo internalid  da tabela reference_vendor ***para todos os registros*** (uma vez que não existe nenhum critério no where) usando como fonte a junção das tabelas reference_vendor e contract_reference  pelo campo externalid onde contract_reference .id ='1207847' e contract_reference.record_type = 'vendor'

Comment: explicação massa!!!

Comment: muito obrigada. :) salvou minha vida.